# Ascend P7 Stopped booting after use of DualBootPatcher

Tags: huawei, device-firmware, emui

I have a Huawei Ascend P7-L10 that was running EMUI on android Lollipop (5.1.1). It was working great and ran very well. I installed DualBootPatcher to use MIUI as well and flashed the zip file. I switched to the MIUI rom from the app and rebooted the phone. Now all I see when I turn it on is the Android android image and a page with the title "Unfortunately, boot failed, get more information..." with instructions to shutdown or go to rescue mode.

I have tried using the HiSuite application on Windows 10 to recover it, and I have put the *dload* folder with "UPDATE.APP" inside it on my micro SD card to force install it. I just got a message saying the installation failed and it flashes something about there not being an "UPDATE.APP" on it for a short time as well.

I also tried using fastboot to flash the firmware to the phone, but my bootloader is apparently locked and I have no working way to unlock it.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Attempting any flashing stuff with a locked bootloader is pretty much your own fault. I do remember there are multiple ways to trigger the download mode (with UPDATE.APP) though...

Comment: I tried that with a micro SD card and it didn't seem to work. Is there a way to access internal storage without a full boot maybe?